# Get length of nested JSON property in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

The dart code below accesses nested JSON properties by using `json.decode()`, but there does not seem to be a property for `count`, `length`, or `size`.

Is it possible to get the length of a nested JSON property in Flutter?

**JSON Response**:

```
{
    "obj1":{
        "list1":[
            {"key1":"value1"},
            {"key2":"value2"},
            {"key3":"value3"}
        ]
    }
}
```

**Dart code**:

```
var response = await httpRequest.response;
Map<String, dynamic> responseJson = json.decode(response.data);
print(responseJson['obj1']['list1']); // How to get length?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the length of the map with the length property. It will give you the number of pairs on the map (or submap):

```
    print(responseJson['obj1'].length);
    result: 1
    print(responseJson['obj1']['list1'].length);   
    result 3
```

Comment: I'v never felt so misled by Android Studio. `length` wasn't available among the list of properties in autocomplete.

Comment: @crayden FYI it's because data types inside a decoded json response are dynamic. If you cast it as a list `final list = responseJson['obj1']['list1'] as List` then you'll get auto complete for Lists.